# Display list of values using carosel in angular6

Tags: typescript, carousel, angular6

Getting the values in a list model.How to display a list of values using carosel.

```
this.http.get('/api/test/' + this.authService.namespace
      , options)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Values' + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.sample= data.json();
```

Comment: let's use a library like this https://github.com/leo6104/ngx-slick-carousel

Comment: I want to display carosel in vertical type in list values

Comment: you could try customizing it with css, or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Actually I am displaying the values in list , I want the list of values in slide show in vertical type.

Comment: yeah. if you realize an horizontal carousel you should be able to adapt only some css rules to change direction. be sure to choose a carousel lib that use flexbox display

Comment: I want to display like that. But the following link is in angularjs, Im looking as angular6 , Type script.
https://codepen.io/mustaphakd/pen/EghpL